# Wrong display when I have more than 9 chapters in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment

I'm in a really bad situation with my ToC in the book that I write. Everything is fine until the 9th chapter. There's the "9", some space and then the name of the chapter. 
But on the 10th (or more) chapter, the "1" of the "10" is under the "9". So the "0" of the "10" is where there should be a space. As a result, there is no space between the number of the chapter and the name of the chapter.

I expected that LaTeX would deal with it as it does with the bibliography entries. It leaves some space empty on the start of one digit numbers so they will be all aligned at the end. (For example, when we have [9] and [10], the 0 is under the 9)

Let me show you my preamble as well

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[english, greek]{babel}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{extarrows}
\usepackage[makeroom,Smaller]{cancel}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[top=3.2cm, bottom=2.8cm, left=2.9cm, right=2.9cm,headsep=9mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{slashbox}
\usepackage[official]{eurosym}

(Here there are some commands but they've got nothing to do with that)

\begin {document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\mbox{}
\newpage


\mainmatter
.
.
.
```

Comment: Instead of including all the packages in your preamble, it's better when asking for help to construct the smallest complete document that shows the problem you are having.  The one lockstep created in his answer is a good example of what a minimal example for your problem would look like.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [tocloft](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) package. Page 11 of its documentation describes how to set chapter resp. section numbers flushright.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\newlength{\mylength}
\setlength{\mylength}{0.7em}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{\hspace*{\mylength}}
\addtolength{\cftchapnumwidth}{\mylength}
\addtolength{\cftsecindent}{\mylength}
\addtolength{\cftsubsecindent}{\mylength}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

% The following code line is added to make the example truly minimal
\setcounter{chapter}{8} 

\chapter{Nine}

\chapter{Ten}

\section{Ten.One}

\subsection{Ten.One.One}

\end{document}
```

Comment: For some reason it's not working on me. There's an error saying
Command \mylen already defined. 
But there's no other command like that in my preamble. It works when I change the name to \myleng. But the sections don't look so well now

Comment: @Alex: I updated my example.

Comment: Wow it works very nice now. The only problem is the gap between 
9.1 SectionName and the 10.1 SectionName. On the subsection the same. 
In the case of 9.1 the gap is normal but in the 10.1 is a bit too small but that's alright if you can't fix that. I'm happy as it is now, although I would be happier if you could fix it (pleaseeeeeeeeee...)

Comment: @Alex: I updated again -- please check. Also, I'm afraid that the width of the box containing the section number can only be set once, i.e. the gap must become smaller if the section number becomes wider (10.1.1 instead of 9.1.1).

Comment: When I create a new tex file with your example as it is, it works like a charm. 
But on my book the problem still remains. I don't know why. Thank's anyway. I'm happy like that!

Comment: @Alex You could also take a look at the `tocloft` documentation, now that lockstep has got you started.  You can increase the space of the section numbers by adding `\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{2.5em}` to your preamble, and adjust the width as needed.  Since the numbers are being set flush left, the space between the longer section numbers and the shorter ones will always be slightly different.  You could use the same technique as in lockstep's code to set them flush right, but I don't recommend it.